# How to turn a Width*Height sized 1d array of RGB565 values into an image in C++

Tags: c++, file, rgb

I have a 1d array of 16 bit integers that represent RGB565 pixels. In my understanding this means:

The 5 most significant bits represent red.
The 6 next bits represent green.
The 5 least significant bits represent blue.

the size of the array is width * height and they are known values.

How do I turn this into a file that I can view?

The file format doesn't matter, as long as it's something I can view!

I am aware of Magick++.h but I'm not sure it can do that. I am also open to command line tools for suggestions.

Comment: Suggestions of libraries, tools, etc... are off-topic for stackoverflow.com. You will find that the technical specifications of some common, basic, file formats like `.bmp` are easily searchable on the Internet. Find some technical documentation. Read it. Understand it. And simply write a C++ program that implements it, by converting your 565 image to it. If you run into some issues you can't figure out, you can post a question on stackoverflow.com, with a [mre], but in all cases you must show your work first.

Comment: There is a very detailed description of [BMP in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). Have a look specifically on [Pixel format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_format). I assume that Windows Paint is able to view it (if encoded correctly) as well as other image viewers.

Comment: A simple way is to save it as raw (binary) like: `FILE *f; fopen_s(&f, "im.raw", "wb");fwrite(A, 2, width*height, f);fclose(f);` and view the raw file using [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) (in Windows). Sory for using C and not C++.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of methods. I used a random sample image I found from [here](https://github.com/solderjs/image-examples/blob/master/test/reference.rgb565).

---

First, using **ImageMagick**:

```
magick -size 720x480 RGB565:reference.rgb565 -auto-level result.jpg
```

---

Second, using **ffmpeg**:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb565 -s 720x480 -i reference.rgb565 -f image2 -vcodec png image.png
```

---

The third method uses **Perl**, which is actually included in all **macOS** versions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use autodie;

$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 3) {
    printf "Usage: RGB565.pl width height RB565file > result.ppm\n";
    exit;
}

$w=$ARGV[0];  # width
$h=$ARGV[1];  # height
$f=$ARGV[2];  # filename

# Open file as raw
open my $fh, '<:raw', $f;

# Output PPM header https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example
print "P6\n$w $h\n255\n";

# Read w*h pixels
for(my $p=0; $p<($w * $h); $p++){
    # Read 2 bytes of RGB565
    read $fh, my $RGB565, 2;
    my ($b2, $b1) = unpack 'cc', $RGB565;
    # Write 3 bytes of RGB888
    my $r = $b1 & 0xF8;
    my $g = (($b1 & 0x07)<<5) | (($b2 & 0xE0)>>3);
    my $b = ($b2 & 0x1F) << 3;
    printf "%c%c%c", $r, $g, $b;
}
```

The result is the same:

[image]

**Keywords**: Image processing, RGB565, ImageMagick, ffmpeg, convert RGB565 to PNG, convert RGB565 to JPEG, prime.